# What's the point of brushing teeth in the morning?

Tags: dentistry

Why should I brush my teeth in the morning? My teeth are just going to get dirty again when I eat breakfast 5 minutes later. Plus, I've already done an extensive cleaning (floss, brush, mouthwash) the night before. My teeth should not be getting dirtier as I sleep.

I've heard people say their breakfast tastes better after brushing their teeth. I've never experienced bad taste from not brushing. I only care about the hygiene reasons for brushing in the morning.

Comment: As an aside, I recently learned that flossing is *extremely important* in preventing infection (that's what gingivitis is) and losing your teeth!

Comment: In addition to the other answers, not disputing them but I don't want to add on to them, there is a coating applied from toothpaste that protects your teeth from subsequent bacterial infection. There are antibiotic agents in toothpaste to protect the toothpaste itself from spoilage but also inhibit growth on the teeth themselves. This is manifested by a slipperiness you can feel.

Comment: "My teeth are just going to get dirty again when I eat breakfast 5 minutes later." So brush after you eat rather than before

Comment: @KonradRudolph - Classic! Don't suppose you have a pic you could link to of that pamphlet?

Comment: Because when your mother asks if you've brushed your teeth this morning you don't want to lie.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Brushing at night is the most important. Saliva naturally fights the growth of bacteria on your teeth. Your mouth dries out at night and reduces your mouth's ability to do this. Ideally, you would keep your teeth clean at all times but that's of course not realistic. A while back I read many websites and opinions about this very question. The main consensus seemed to be that people brush in the morning because it makes them feel good to start their day with a clean mouth (not because it's the best time to do it).

[Here is a discussion about it on Ask MetaFilter](http://ask.metafilter.com/64633/Whens-the-best-time-to-brush-your-pearly-whites):

> During the day, you're flapping your jaw, drinking water, chewing gum, and moving your tongue, all of which help to clean things off of your teeth. At night, your mouth is much less active, which allows bacteria more time to grow without being mechanically sloughed off.
>
> Many years ago my orthodontist told me that it was most important to brush your teeth before going to sleep (I guess either for the night, or for a nap). Saliva production is down, and if you happen to sleep with your mouth gaping open, your teeth dry out and don't have that protective layer of saliva. Just the lack of movement of your lips and tongue while sleeping gives decay more of an opportunity to do its dirty work.

[Here is an article by Dr. H.S. Chawla](http://positivepersonality.blogspot.com/2009/02/right-time-for-brushing-teeth.html):

> Brushing before meals: Most people normally brush their teeth in the morning before breakfast. That is beneficial, as you have reduced the number of bacteria before exposing them to food. The amount of acid production is expected to be less, and so would be the damage to the teeth. You get an additional benefit if you use fluoride tooth paste, as the fluoride gets incorporated into the enamel and makes it strong and resistant to the effect of acid. (Fluoride converts the hydroxyl-apatite of enamel to calcium fluor-apatite).

If you are going to brush in the morning, it may actually be better to brush before you eat rather than after.

> brushing right after eating is not at all advised, as the acid produced [by bacteria] has already begun the process of eroding enamel. If you brush promptly after a meal, you rub off part of the dissolved minerals of the enamel.

Comment: +1 you explained brushing before/after eating just right. People usually have the wrong idea of this.

Comment: +1 well explained and also debunked the efficiency theory posted in the comments to the original question.

Comment: Brushing teeth is a medical intervention. Medical interventions generally need controlled studies to be accepted. Your post simply lists a bunch of pseudoscientific discussion. Could you provide real sources?

Comment: So, this is a bit tangential, but do semi-annual tooth cleanings help? Just because dentists sell this service does not make it good.

Comment: I agree that brushing at night is most important, though the next sentence is BS:"your teeth dry out and don't have that protective layer of saliva" since bacteria can't live in a dry environment. Having completely dry teeth would actually be a very effective way to keep them from rotting.

Comment: A web forum discussion and a link to a blog from an institute that develops "mind power" are not good sources. Would you be willing to back this up with proper sources?

Comment: I am so confused about why this post has upvotes...Isn't this the type of post we want to downvote?

Comment: Weak, I'm downvoting for poor sources. OOps, can't, not enough rep.

Comment: This answer lacks references to real, scientific sources. I suggest searching https://scholar.google.com or https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed to find peer-reviewed literature that will support your point

Answer (score 55):

Expanding on [Logicbird's answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2411/whats-the-point-of-brushing-teeth-in-the-morning/2413#2413), here is what the [British Dental Health Foundation](http://www.emaxhealth.com/79/1063.html) says:

> **Acidic foods and drinks, such as
>   oranges, grapefruit and fruit juices**
>   that are often eaten at breakfast
>   time, **soften the enamel on your teeth**.
>
> **Brushing immediately afterward wears
>   the enamel away**, and can cause dental
>   erosion, which may lead to pain and
>   extreme sensitivity in the teeth, and
>   also lead to cosmetic problems.
>
> **The saliva in your mouth neutralises
>   the acidity** and restores its natural
>   balance. However research has shown
>   that **this can take up to an hour**.

---

Their tips for avoiding dental erosion are:

> - brush teeth before breakfast if you    have fruit or fruit juice, or
> - wait one hour after eating or    drinking anything acidic before
>     brushing
> - use a straw when drinking acidic    drinks to reduce contact with teeth
> - drink water and milk between meals in    preference to juice and fizzy
>     drinks
> - chew sugar-free gum - this will    produce more saliva to help cancel
>     out acid in your mouth
> - finish a meal with cheese or milk to    help neutralise any acids

---

The [NHS](http://www.nhs.uk/Livewell/dentalhealth/Pages/Teethcleaningguide.aspx) says the same:

> Brush your teeth in the morning before
>   breakfast and last thing at night
>   before you go to bed (and ideally at
>   least an hour after your evening
>   meal).
>
> **Brushing your teeth straight after a
>   meal can damage your teeth, especially
>   if you've had fruit, fizzy drinks,
>   wine or any other food that contains
>   acid**. This is because tooth enamel is
>   softened by the acid and can be worn
>   away by brushing. Waiting an hour
>   gives your saliva chance to neutralise
>   the acid.

Comment: If I brush my teeth before I drink an acidic juice, that means there's little plaque or saliva to prevent the juice from breaking down the enamel. So why brush before drinking?

Comment: @JoJo - Brushing actually [induces salivary secretion](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20224201)

Comment: It says here at one point enamel get softer. Does that means that it gets harder again if you leave it alone or...?

Comment: @Amer - My dentist said that fluoride (e.g. in toothpaste) would help harden it.

Comment: @Amer - [Here is a study saying](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1863431): `Rehardening effects following milk or saliva exposures respectively were evident, presumably due to deposited organic and mineral material on the enamel surface.`

Comment: This leaves out the effects on taste that can occur when brushing before drinking fruit juices and the like.